# Why does music still loop, when my PC freezes?

Tags: audio, freeze

Unfortunately it happens rather regularly, that some i/o job or some other activity clogs all the cpu power on my rather old linux machine and leaves me with a frozen desktop, where not even the mouse will move, for some time.

Rather than trying to troubleshoot here with you, I was wondering:

Why does music continue to play, while my PC is seemingly frozen (probably a process independent of the desktop) and why does it continue to loop the last second or so, after that process seems to have frozen as well?

Would it not make more sense, that the application in the background, that produces the sound, stops as soon as it's buffer is empty? How come the sound starts looping all of a sudden?

I've seen this behaviour on Windows as well, even on my Android phone. For a specific example, I had a YouTube Video open, while creating a very large gzip archive, which brought the CPU down with i/o wait.
After still being able to listen to the video for about 3 minutes after the Desktop froze, unresponsive to mouse and Keyboard it then started to loop the last second and about half a minute later crashed entirely.

Comment: I've seen this type of behavior on multiple devices and operating systems with music players, websites and videos being the source of the audio. I agree, that it is a broad question, but it should have an answer, that is not platform specific and is the same for all these instances. Since I'm not asking for a specific fix, I don't see how the question is too broad to be able to have an answer. It would be nice, if specific suggestions on how to improve the question could be made.

Comment: IMHO it's not really that broad a question. Basically (simplified a lot) the OS sends a block of data to the audio hardware, and when the hardware is ready for another block it sends an interrupt and the OS sends the next block. If the OS is stalled for some reason, it can't respond to the interrupt and hence the old data is still in the audio hardware, and hence that gets repeated over and over.

Comment: The reasoning for this Q is addressed in this meta Q&A: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3221/why-do-questions-get-put-on-hold-without-a-reason-given

Comment: As a hint about this, I believe PCM sound is streamed to a digital-analog converter chip separate from the CPU; i.e., that part is very low intensity, processor usage wise, and may not be much affected when the system or an application appears "frozen".  However, if the application itself is having problems getting resources to decode from a non PCM source or whatever, there may be an underlying buffer in the sound library, held open and active by the application, that causes the looping effect. $0.02